# Quicksort array of strings gives error in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, sorting, quicksort

I'm new to this site and kind of new to C as well. The last 2 days I am studying the sorting algorithms, and decided to test my skills on modyfying the quicksort for integers to a quicksort for array of strings. Basically, I have this text file:

```
2367 2011-11-15 15:00 2011-11-15 20:55
2368 2011-11-15 17:15 2011-11-16 01:50
2369 2011-11-15 20:00 2011-11-16 05:55
2370 2011-11-15 20:00 2011-11-16 05:50
2371 2011-11-15 22:50 2011-11-16 03:45
2372 2011-11-12 17:00 2011-11-12 19:20
2373 2011-11-13 13:55 2011-11-13 21:35
2374 2011-11-14 03:40 2011-11-14 06:15
```

This file has 3 parts which I have already stored in 3 arrays of strings.

- The sip array contains `sip[0] == "2367"`, `sip[1] == "2368"` etc.
- The std array contains the first dates and times, `std[0] == "2011-11-15 15:00"`, `std[1] == "2011-11-15 17:15"` etc.
- At last the etd array contains the second dates and times, `etd[0] == "2011-11-15 20:55"`, `etd[1] == "2011-11-16 01:50"` etc.

So, I'm trying to use Quicksort algorithm for array of strings to sort the above text file based on the std array, so the expected result would be:

```
2372 2011-11-12 17:00 2011-11-12 19:20  (moved first)
2373 2011-11-13 13:55 2011-11-13 21:35  (moved second)
2374 2011-11-14 03:40 2011-11-14 06:15  (moved third)
2367 2011-11-15 15:00 2011-11-15 20:55
2368 2011-11-15 17:15 2011-11-16 01:50
2369 2011-11-15 20:00 2011-11-16 05:55
2370 2011-11-15 20:00 2011-11-16 05:50
2371 2011-11-15 22:50 2011-11-16 03:45
```

This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void quickSortMain(char items[][17], char etd[][17], char SP[][5], int count);
void quickSort(char items[][17], char etd[][17], char SP[][5], int left, int right);

int main () {
.

.

quickSortMain(std, etd, sip, count);
// std and etd have 16 characters, so std[][17] and etd[][17]
// sip has 4 characters, so sip[][5]

.

.

}

void quickSort(char items[][17], char etd[][17], char SP[][5], int left, int right)
{
  int i, j;
  char *x;
  char temp[10];

  i = left;
  j = right;
  x = items[(left+right)/2];

  do {
    while((strcmp(items[i],x) < 0) && (i < right)) {
       i++;
    }
    while((strcmp(items[j],x) > 0) && (j > left)) {
        j--;
    }
    if(i <= j) {
      strcpy(temp, items[i]);
      strcpy(items[i], items[j]);
      strcpy(items[j], temp);

      strcpy(temp1, etd[i]);
      strcpy(etd[i], etd[j]);
      strcpy(etd[j], temp1);

      strcpy(temp2, SP[i]);
      strcpy(SP[i], SP[j]);
      strcpy(SP[j], temp2);

      i++;
      j--;
   }
  } while(i <= j);

  if(left < j) {
     quickSort(items, etd, SP, left, j);
  }
  if(i < right) {
     quickSort(items, etd, SP, i, right);
  }
}
```

But, something goes wrong. Could you help me finding it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use `qsort()` instead :)

Comment: @BlueMoon: I don't think `qsort()` will work when data is spread out in 3 different arrays. Besides it is not guaranteed to implement the QuickSort algorithm.

Comment: @user consider putting your data in a single array, then sort that single array, then, if needed, break that original single array into 3 different arrays.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers, but I don't want to sort based on the four first letter, but based one the first date-time, check the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need to split your file into three arrays.  Since you sort by the first number, the result will be correct, provided the values of the first part always contain four characters.  If they don't, then your code will give error because strcpy assumes the target has enough space allocated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to sort by the date-time, check the expected result..

Answer (score 0):

There is a `qsort()` in C standard library, you could use it to sort your records.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
record_cmp (const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    const char *a = (const char *)pa + 5;
    const char *b = (const char *)pb + 5;
    return strncmp(a, b, 16);
}

int
main(void) {
    char record[][40] = {
        "2367 2011-11-15 15:00 2011-11-15 20:55",
        "2368 2011-11-15 17:15 2011-11-16 01:50",
        "2369 2011-11-15 20:00 2011-11-16 05:55",
        "2370 2011-11-15 20:00 2011-11-16 05:50",
        "2371 2011-11-15 22:50 2011-11-16 03:45",
        "2372 2011-11-12 17:00 2011-11-12 19:20",
        "2373 2011-11-13 13:55 2011-11-13 21:35",
        "2374 2011-11-14 03:40 2011-11-14 06:15",
    };
    size_t ele_num = sizeof(record)/sizeof(record[0]);

    qsort(record, ele_num, sizeof(record[0]), record_cmp);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ele_num; i++) {
        printf("record[%zu] = %s\n", i, record[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The original question has the data split into 3 different arrays.

Comment: @pmg There is no need to do that to sort those data. If he split them for other purpose, he still could do that after them are sorted.

Comment: Also `qsort()` does not necessarily implement the QuickSort algorithm.

Comment: @pmg Yes, you are right. You can use it to sort some data, but you cannot use it to learn how quick sort algorithm works. If the asker's intention is to learn how quick sort algorithm works, then it is an irrelevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

With ref to your source code, I see there is mismatch between the type of parameters passed to below function and its expected list of arguments:

```
 quickSort(items, 0, etd, SP, count-1);
 void quickSort(char items[][17], char etd[][17], char SP[][5], int left, int right)
```

You should call the function as:

```
 quickSort(items, etd, SP, 0, count-1);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, I changed it but still doesn't work, it gives segfault for some reason (updated my initial post).